# When I run labled LDA by Stanford TMT, I always get this error, "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.max"

Tags: lda

This is the scalar code to train the data set. What is the problem?

```
val tokenizer = {
  SimpleEnglishTokenizer() ~>            // tokenize on space and punctuation
  CaseFolder() ~>                        // lowercase everything
  WordsAndNumbersOnlyFilter() ~>         // ignore non-words and non-numbers
  //MinimumLengthFilter(1) ~>                // take terms with >=3 characters
  PorterStemmer() //~>
  //StopWordFilter("en")
}

val text = {
  source ~>                              // read from the source file
  Columns(4,6) ~>
  Join(" ") ~>                           // select column containing text
  TokenizeWith(tokenizer) ~>             // tokenize with tokenizer above
  TermCounter() //~>                      // collect counts (needed below)
  TermMinimumDocumentCountFilter(0) ~>  // filter terms in <4 docs
  TermDynamicStopListFilter(0) ~>    // filter out 30 most common terms
  TermMinimumDocumentCountFilter(0)   // take only docs with >=5 terms
}

// define fields from the dataset we are going to slice against
val labels = {
  source ~>                              // read from the source file
  Column(5) ~>                           // take column two, the year
  TokenizeWith(WhitespaceTokenizer()) ~> // turns label field into an array
  TermCounter() //~>                       // collect label counts
  TermMinimumDocumentCountFilter(0)     // filter labels in < 10 docs
}

val dataset = LabeledLDADataset(text, labels);

// define the model parameters
val modelParams = LabeledLDAModelParams(dataset);

// Name of the output model folder to generate
val modelPath = file("llda-cvb0-"+dataset.signature+"-"+modelParams.signature);

// Trains the model, writing to the given output path
TrainCVB0LabeledLDA(modelParams, dataset, output = modelPath, maxIterations = 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

the line is wrong `TermDynamicStopListFilter(0) ~>    // filter out 30 most common terms`

It should be 
`TermDynamicStopListFilter(30)`
to filter out words appear more than 30 times, as comments.